# magic files Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I need to find files with .txt file type, which has "hello" on specific byte for example 10th byte.

It would be great to get some explanation with example.

Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it. If there's a tool out there that does what you need, perhaps someone will suggest that you don't need to reinvent the wheel, but it all starts with your code.

Comment: The thing is that I want to learn more about how shell works. So I've tried to use "file" and "magic" I really don't know how to use the correctly. I've read tutorials but still it is not clear for me

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

add to ft_magic
10 string exe 10 type

run in terminal 
file -C -m ft_test

перевірка
  file * -m ft_test